# Perl - build 2D array from 2 arrays of equal length

Tags: perl

So I should preface this by saying I've actually solved this, but the syntax is horrible so I want to see if theres a Perl-ish way of doing it which is nicer.

I have two arrays of length n (`@genes` and `@names`). I want to combine them into a single 2D array of paired values.

My approach right now is;

```
$Num = Number of elements in each array

my @genes = ();
foreach my $i ( 0 .. $num-1 ) {
    foreach my $j ( 0 .. 1 ) {
    if ($j == 0){ push @{ $genes[$i] }, $names[$i];}
    if ($j == 1){ push @{ $genes[$i] }, $lengths[$i];}
    }
}
```

But this requires an explicit line for each additional column (right now I have two - names and length). Also it's hideous. Code only a mother could love.

Any thoughts. Note that

```
@genes = (\@lengths, \@names);
```

Does *not* achieve what I want.

Comment: You did mean to say that you have two arrays `@names` and `@length` that you want to combine into a 2D-array `@genes`, I take it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can at least do this:

```
foreach my $i ( 0 .. $num-1 ) {
    push @genes, [$names[$i], $lengths[$i]];
}
```

If you don't care about the input arrays, you can consume them:

```
push @genes, [shift @names, shift @lengths] while @names;
```

There are also some modules you can use for iterating over multiple lists. For example, using `List::MoreUtils::each_array`:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( each_array );
my $it = each_array( @names, @lengths );
while (my ($n, $l) = $it->()) {
    push @genes, [$n, $l];
}
```

Further, with `List::MoreUtils::pairwise`:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( pairwise );
@genes = pairwise{ [our $a, our $b] } @names, @lengths;
```

Suggested by [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth), with `Algorithm::Loops::MapCarE`:

```
use Algorithm::Loops 'MapCarE';
@genes = MapCarE { \@_ } \( @names, @lengths );
```

Comment: Awesome - that first syntax is clearly a much cleaner implementation (and in hind-site not in anyway Perl specific)

Answer (score 4):

You could write

```
my @genes = map [ $names[$_], $lengths[$_] ], 0 .. $#names;
```

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, your original code can be cleaned up just by removing some
unnecessary logic:

```
foreach my $i ( 0 .. $num-1 ) {
    foreach my $j ( 0 .. 1 ) {
        if ($j == 0){ push @{ $genes[$i] }, $names[$i];}
        if ($j == 1){ push @{ $genes[$i] }, $lengths[$i];}
    }
}
```

You're looping over 0 and 1, then testing if you're on 0 or 1, then
performing one action or the other?  Just perform the two actions each time:

```
foreach my $i ( 0 .. $num-1 ) {
  push @{$genes[$i]}, $names[$i];
  push @{$genes[$i]}, $lengths[$i]
}
```

Possibly you started out wanting to loop over the indexes, then thought you
couldn't do this since the internal arrays didn't exist yet, and fell back to
this `push` construction.  But, er, the arrays don't exist until you `push`
onto them here, either.  Looping over the indexes was fine:

```
my @helper = (\@names, \@lengths);
foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#names ) {
    foreach my $j ( 0 .. 1 ) {
        $genes[$i][$j] = $helper[$j][$i];
    }
}
```